# samsung galaxy does not detected on eclipse adt

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse ADT, but andorid device choiser(ctr + f11) does not detect my samsung galaxy s. I set the debug mode and also I  have installed kies but kies does not detect my phone.

I have windows 8 64bit and in phone i set cyanogenmod

Comment: When you're plugging your Samsung Galaxy S, there is a prompt or a notification to choose the usb mode? If positive, you're choosing the "Only charge" or "Transfer files" mode?

Comment: No, there isn´t any notification? On windows 8 I get the device GT-I9000 with a warning: driver not available

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn on your developer option.
It should be in Developer Options. If your device is running Android 4.2, Developer Options is hidden by default. 
To enable it follow these steps.
Go into Settings > About

Tap on the Build Number entry seven times (Toasts will appear to help you keep count)

Press BACK, and Developer Options should be in the Settings list

Comment: Also ensure that 'Samsung Kies' is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) on your system, you will not face any problem in future with all other Samsung devices as well and at the same time please check USB debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

After Developer Option turn on (tap Build Number 7x in About Phone), do:

Settings --> Developer Options --> USB Debugging.